# Office 2010 Trusted Locations not working after restart

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office-2010, microsoft-word-2010

In Excel 2010, on Windows XP, I am unable to open files - through the open dialog box - from a network drive. The sever has already been added to the Trusted Locations and now most security settings turned down or off.

Excel will show "Downloading ..." on that status bar and a progress bar which doesn't progress. We have left Excel sitting in this state for 30+ minutes and no change.

A similar problem occurs when saving files to network shares.

If we use explorer to navigate to the files and double click them they open flawlessly.

No add-ins are active.

We also have this problem in Word 2010, but the server was not initially in the Trusted Locations. I added it and it worked until the PC was reset, it now exhibits the same issues as Excel where the server is in the Trusted locations but will not open files.

I have tried removing the server from the Trusted Location in both applications, restarting the PC and re-adding them (testing before, after and in-between) and had no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a long time since I posted this question, and a long time since it was moved off of my list of things to do.

In the end we determined that the problem was limited to the user(/local profile) on that machine. Normally we would just recreate the user's profile if it was something like this that we couldn't determine easily, but this user switched to a new machine soon after we made this determination.

Fix would have been to delete local user profile and re-create, re-imaged machine instead.